# How to change the window layouts in VS Code (move Interactive Window to the bottom panel)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, spyder, vscode-extensions

I've been using Spyder for a while and I am new to VS Code.

I like to show my variables panel on the right, the script at the center, and the Interactive Window on the bottom panel just like in the Spyder's MATLAB layout.

When I run a script in `Interactive Window`, the interactive window shows up on the right side of the script window and I can open the variables panel on the right side of it, like in this screenshot:
[image]

I like to move this interactive window to the bottom, where the terminal is in the image, but I cannot do that by drag and drop.

Does anyone know if there is a way to move Interactive Window to the bottom panel?